# Rerun an "imported" external python file in a program?

Tags: python, import, python-import

I'm trying to make a "head" python program capable of running my other programs, which can return to the head program. I am using import to load these files.

In Head:

```
print("Running Tail...")
import Tail
```

This successfully runs Tail.py, which in it has

```
print("This is the program.")
print("Heading back to Head...")
import Head
```

This successfully returns to Head.py. However, when Head.py tries to run Tail.py again, it fails to run Tail again. Perhaps is there a way to "unimport" an imported module for this purpose? Many thanks!

EDIT: I understand that it would be best to use a function, however, this was a simplification, and eventually, I want to have complicated programs for heads and tails, to the point where heads will involve other programs, and tail programs can run at a larger scale, using defines and such themselves. I want "Head" to work like a game launcher from a library.

Comment: That's not what `import` is for. You need to read about how to write and call functions. Consider taking the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/).

Comment: Not really how you should use import, but you can just lose the `import Head` in the Tail.py. It will return to Head.py when it's done running Tail

Comment: Imported files will only be run once. To accomplish what you're trying to do you need to use a function. Functions can be rerun as many times as you want. You can place your function inside of Head.py or Tail.py, but it would be easiest to keep everything inside of Head.py for now.

Comment: "I understand that it would be best to use a function, however, this was a simplification" - in more complicated cases, you should still use functions. This is not what `import` is for, regardless of the complexity level.